# PHP Filter a 3D array by the different values of one key

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I have this 3D array and I'm trying to filter it by the field 'categories' held in the inner array but I can't get it quite right.

```
  Array(
 'type' => 'success',
 'value => array (
     0 => array (
         'id' => 1,
         'joke' => 'Chuck Norris uses ribbed condoms inside out, so he gets the pleasure.',
          'categories' => array());
     1 => array (
          'id' => 2,
          'joke' => 'MacGyver can build an airplane out of gum and paper clips. Chuck Norris can kill him and take it.',
          'categories' => array(              
            [0] => nerdy                        
            ));
   );
);
```

I have tryed with array_filter but I can't get it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: please add your current code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a *good* solution or not to the question - and equally, not sure if it's safe to change the value of $x['value'] after filtering, however in terms of using array_filter, the following would do filter on the category value:

```
class Filter {
    private $string = '';

    public function __construct($string2) {
        $this->string = $string2;
    }

    public function catfilter($x) {
        if( in_array( $this->string, $x['categories'] ) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function filter( $x ) {
        $t = array_filter($x['value'], array( $this, "catfilter"));
        $x['value'] = $t;
        return $x;
    }


}

 $x = array(
 'type' => 'success',
 'value' => array (
     '0' => array (
         'id' => '1',
         'joke' => 'C',
          'categories' => array() ),
     '1' => array (
          'id' => '2',
          'joke' => 'M',
          'categories' => array(          '0' => 'nerdy')  )
   )
);

$f = new Filter('nerdy');
print_r($f->filter($x));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It does work quite rigth thanks a lot, now what should I do if I want to filter the ones without categories as well, with the code as it is won't show them.

Comment: Getting messy - but could do: public function c($x) {
       if ( empty( $x['categories'] ) ) {
         return true;
       }
    }


    public  function emptyfilter($x) {
        $t = array_filter($x['value'], array( $this, "c"));
        $x['value'] = $t;
        return $x;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you name your 3D array `$data`, you can use:

```
if($data['type'] == 'success'){
    $results = filter_by_category($data['value'],'nerdy')
}
```

to just pass the 2D part of your array to the filter function.

Then, you can filter the data set with something like this:

```
function filter_by_category($dataset, $category){
    // define an empty array to populate with the results
    $output = array();

    // iterate the dataset
    foreach($dataset as $row){
        // check if the category we are looking for exists in this row
        if(in_array($category,$row['categories'])){
            // if it does, add it to the output array
            $output[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```